# Do I need to destroy semaphores in Objective-C with ARC?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, semaphore

I am working on iOS Core Audio following the suggestion from this post: [Core Audio render thread and thread signalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844429/core-audio-render-thread-and-thread-signalling).

In the updated answer, which uses `dispatch_semaphore_t`, I understand that I don't need to call `dispatch_release` when ARC is enabled after reading this post: [Does ARC support dispatch queues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618632/does-arc-support-dispatch-queues).

However, in the original answer when `semaphore_t` is used (*see below code snippets*), I cannot find reference for whether I need to destroy the semaphore by calling `semaphore_destroy` when ARC is enabled. Can someone please help?

```
semaphore_t mSemaphore;

kern_return_t result = semaphore_create(mach_task_self(), &mSemaphore, SYNC_POLICY_FIFO, 0);

// Do stuff with semaphore wait and signal ...

kern_return_t result = semaphore_destroy(mach_task_self(), mSemaphore);
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to destroy Mach semaphores manually. ARC does not automatically manage Mach semaphores. And, by analogy with dispatch semaphores, if ARC did manage them, it would disallow the use of `semaphore_destroy()`. If it's not disallowing that, then you can and should use it.

Note that Mach semaphores are not reference counted. There are no retain and release operations, just create and destroy. There's no difference between a strong or unsafe unretained reference. All references are, effectively, unsafe unretained. Without reference counting, ARC can't reason about the semaphore objects as they are passed around through code.